# Console not writing class object name

Tags: c#, .net, console.writeline

C# in Visual Studio... very simple main and class method. When running, my program only reads out "Hi friend", and not "Otis". Any ideas to what's going on?

```
using System;

namespace Project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {       
            Console.WriteLine("Hi friend");        
            Cow myCow = new Cow("Otis");
            Console.WriteLine(myCow.Name);
        }
    }
    
    class Cow
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Cow(string name)
        {
            name = Name;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the assignment in the constructor reversed - you're assigning the (empty) member `Name` to the argument `name`, instead of the other way round:

```
class Cow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Cow(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }   
}
```

Note - using `this` would make it more explicit, and easier to catch such mistakes:

```
class Cow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Cow(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got the Constructor parameter assigment switched. Should be like this:

```
Name = name;
```